# Excel - Zodiac Signs and Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel fail in which I use several worksheets; the action is with Workers (Töötajad) worksheet. In this worksheet, there is the main table, called the same name (I can change the name but it does not matter). I show you this table (It is in Estonian - You should not worry about the language, for I may translate everything without Google translate):

[image: A part of my Table]

Now you ought to pay your attention to the "Tähtkuju" (Zodiac Sign), where it is written "Veevalaja" (Aquarius). As you may see, I attempted to give each person its Zodiac sign based on its birthday (Sünnikuupäev).

There is also worksheet "Lisa", "Appendix" where there is the table associating Zodiac signs with Dates:

[[image: Zodiac Sign and Dates2]

On the left column, you can find the Zodiac signs sorted in ascending order, begging with Capricorn. On the other one, you can see Dates associated with these signs.

**Problem**: I have person's dates, so I must associate these with Zodiac sign, so that each person would be characterized with its Astrology. My attempt is horrible, but I spent one or two hours:

=@IFS(OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,3,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,4,2)),INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,3,1), ... )

I put here part of the formula, because you can see my logic: I refer to Appendix worksheet and take Zodiac and Dates from there to my working space "Workers", where I am going to use that data. Okay, now I must just compare dates and give each person Zodiac sign. Unfortunaly, formula returns only one Zodiac sign, which Aquarius; if you replace OR with AND you get either #VALUE or #SPILL errors. The implicit date sign @ fixed #SPILL but not #VALUE, which means I misunderstood something. Now I provide you with the full formula - but before doing so, I tell you that I go from the first row to the law with respect to the Table in Appendix. I can copy that table to my working space but that does not matter.

=@IFS(OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,3,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,4,2)),INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,3,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,4,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX( 'Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,5,2)),INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,4,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,5,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX( 'Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,6,2)),INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,5,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev>= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,6,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,7,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,6,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,7,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX( 'Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,8,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,7,1),OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,8,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,9,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,8,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,9,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,10,2)),  INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,9,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,10,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX( 'Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,11,2)),  INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,9,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev>= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,11,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,11,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,10,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,11,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,12,2)),  INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,12,1), OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,12,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,13,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,13,1),OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,13,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,14,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,14,1),OR(@Sünnikuupäev >= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,14,2),@Sünnikuupäev <= INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,15,2)), INDEX('Excel_Ivanov (1).xlsx'!Needing,15,1))

**Or what I misunderstood?** **Any clues?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'm rusty in **Excel** & and Reddy's answer wasn't posted when I started playing (In **LibreOffice Calc**, can't affort **MS Office** :D).

I think it's the year portions of the dates that causing unexpected results in your comparisons. I opted to use VLOOKUP with a day-of-year approach to determining the sign. The lookup table is baseed on a 365-day year. For persons born in a leap year after Feb-29, the day-of-year is corrected by subtracting 1. Since you're unlikely to deal with birthdays in 1900 or 2100, The 100/400 rule for leap years was omitted from calculation.

[image]

- **Columns A-D** contain the lookup table, with day-of-year calculated from the Start Date for each sign.
- **Column F** contains sample birthdays.
- **Column G** contains my original, hard-to-read, single-cell formula to clculate the sigh. (shown below.)
- **Column H** is an intermediate vaule used several times: the true day-of-year for the birthday in column F.
- **Column J** contains the formula to look up the sign using the value from column H.

My original single-cell lookup formula was:

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(MOD(YEAR(F14),4),F14-DATEVALUE("1/1/" & YEAR(F14)),DATEVALUE(MONTH(F14) & "/" & DAY(F14) & "/" & (YEAR(F14)-1) )-DATEVALUE("1/1/" & (YEAR(F14)-1))),$A$2:$D$14,3)
```

Comment: All solutions are given to me are not helpful, except for yours, since I have not checked it (due to not having enough amount of time). The reason why your answer become accepted is because I feel that the idea is behind DATEVALUE (I evaluated my formulas explicitly by Excel; all my Dates are "232412", so not a date at all, hence Excel must compare Dates not number). Here comes your solution. Note: IFS does not help. The actual problem is DATE Format, though all dates are in that format, when put into cells, but they are not, when we refer to them...

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt the below formula. IT checks if the date on E11 is greater than dates on the lookup table `$B$1:$B$13`. If not, it returns a result. IF the date is not available (24 to 31 December), it returns the last row(13). the `INDEX` function returns the zodiac sign associated with the row (date)

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$13,IFNA(MATCH(FALSE,E11>=$B$1:$B$13,0)-1,13))
```

[image]

Comment: That might be solution. I like it but still #Value and displayed only one sign of Zodiac. I do not know why - I have the same story with XLOOKUP which persistently gives me #VALUE though I make everything that the function wishes me to. Anyway, do not rush into answering my comment below your answer - I will try until it works.

Comment: @sergeiivanov [How to correct a #VALUE! error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e#:~:text=%23VALUE%20is%20Excel%27s%20way%20of,the%20exact%20cause%20of%20it.). You should check how you are referencing the cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the table slightly, you can get the Sign for any birthday,*(not just 2020)* by using `VLOOKUP()`.  With this in **D1** through **F13**:

[image]

Put any date in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATE(2020,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),D:F,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That is a solution.